# Update in Google Cloud Storage library

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am working on a project and it requires the latest version of Google Cloud Storage client in Google App Engine app. Where can I find the latest version?

Comment: Have you tried doing a web search for the client library for the language of your choice?

Comment: Yes, I did and even landed on the official google site, but was not able to get an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can find those versions in the official Google App Engine documentation. It is suggested to use the versions mentioned in the documentation as they are the one that works perfectly with the examples also provided in the documentation.

There are several programming languages that are supported with the Google Cloud Storage client. You can see them in [App Engine > Using Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/using-cloud-storage) documentation.

- Google Cloud Storage client for [Python](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-cloud-storage#edit_project_configuration_and_install_dependencies) (google-cloud-storage==1.13.2)
- Google Cloud Storage client for [Java](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/using-cloud-storage#edit_project_configuration_and_install_dependencies) (1.62.0)
- Google Cloud Storage client for [Node.js](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/using-cloud-storage#edit_project_configuration_and_install_dependencies) ("@google-cloud/storage": "1.6.0")
- Google Cloud Storage client for [Go](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/using-cloud-storage) (Version not specified)
- Google Cloud Storage client for [Ruby](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/ruby/using-cloud-storage) (Version not specified)
- Google Cloud Storage client for [PHP](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/using-cloud-storage#edit_project_configuration_and_install_dependencies) ("google/cloud-storage": "^1.0")
- Google Cloud Storage client for [.NET](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/dotnet/using-cloud-storage) (Version not specified)